# multithreading sqlite requests in phonegap android 2.2 / 3.0

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I have an app running in phonegap / cordova. It needs to make a request to the sqlite database that takes a few seconds on slower devices. I was wondering if this can be done not on the main thread?

I'm currently running cordova 2.2.0, but will migrate to 3.0 in time, so a solution that only applies to that is fine.

I'm using

```
testDB = window.openDatabase("testDB", "1.0", "test DB", 1000000);
```

to start the database.

I've heard it's possible to write a plugin in java to do this. If so are there any good implementations of this available without having to write my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, and am using the pgsqlite plugin, at:

https://github.com/pgsqlite